# Github action stuck at Firebase deploy

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-platform, github-actions

I'm trying to create a **GitHub Action** that deploys my **Angular** app on **Firebase**. When I run it, it gets stuck at the this part :
[image]

this is the terminal of the Github Action VM, so i cannot interact with it.
Is it possible to skip this part and configure it without asking for this step?

This is my **actions.yml** :

[image]

Comment: It's been a while but should it be "firebase deploy" and not "ng deploy"? Also you have a trailing && which you don't need since there's nothing else to execute after.

Comment: Relevant: https://askubuntu.com/questions/338857/automatically-enter-input-in-command-line